# store selection from multiselect element inside string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple select box like

```
<select id="myMultiSelect" class="multiselect form-control" name="Status" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="AA">AA option</option>
   <option value="BB">BB option</option>  
     ...
  <option value="FF">FF option</option>  


</select>
```

How can I usig jquery store selected values inside string separated with comma like

```
var string = "AA,BB,CC";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get the array of values and then join them:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7xwaL433/)

```
var selectValueString = $('#myMultiSelect > option').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');

console.log(selectValueString); // "AA,BB,FF"
```

Alternatively, without jQuery:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/30phLtda/)

```
var options = document.querySelectorAll('#myMultiSelect > option');
var selectValueString = Array.prototype.map.call(options, function(el){
    return el.value;
}).join(',');

console.log(selectValueString); // "AA,BB,FF"
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a vanilla method.

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign it to variable. The `.val()` returns an array of values:

```
var myval = $('select#myMultiSelect').val();
```

Here is a sample fiddle to show it working: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/6jyrfcfo/